# Can't access data in mdf database file on other computers

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, mdf

I'm developing an app in wpf and I created an .mdf database to store my data. The problem comes when I compress the release `.exe` with their `.mdf` database and try to execute it in another computer.

It seems that the application can't access to the data stored, but I don't know why...

To access my DB I created a Linq to SQL object called `IMEIDB.dbml`, declared a variable

```
private DataBase.IMEIDBDataContext db = new DataBase.IMEIDBDataContext();
```

and then used Linq

```
var query = from t in db.TerminalesCorta select t;
```

These are my connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="RIMEI3.Properties.Settings.conexion" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataBase\IMEIDB.mdf;Integrated Security=False;Connect Timeout=30"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="RIMEI3.Properties.Settings.IMEIDBConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataBase\IMEIDB.mdf;Integrated Security=False"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Is there an error message? How and where are you trying to access the MDF?

Comment: There's no error code, It seems that don't retrieve the data, because the results show me some NaN values. I can't debug the code on the other computer... Also, I updated the retrieve method.

Comment: What are you using to access the MDF? SQLExpress, SQLServer, LocalDB?

Comment: Updated the question with my connection Strings

Comment: Are you generating/extracting the MDF file in the directory `|DataDirectory|\DataBase\IMEIDB.mdf` on the other computer? I am suspecting that you are trying to read from a dbfile that is not there.

Comment: Yes, the file is always in that location, /Database/IMEIDB.mdf

Comment: Since you use |DataDirectory| the path will start where the .exe is executed. So your directory looks like that? Folder (*.exe, Database) -> Database (IMEIDB.mdf)? With "Folder" and "Database" being the names of the Directories and the items in the braces (*.exe, Database) being the items in the specific folders?

Comment: Yes, the database is in the correct place. The release directory has the .exe and a folder called Database with IMEIDB.mdf inside